Teens filming on a ghost train ride
I am recalling a scene from a horror movie, although it could be a parody (like Scary Movie). A group of teenagers are in an old fairground ride, either a ghost train or mini train style ride. They are making a film or documentary. They manage to get the ride to work, but a number of them are killed. One guy got electrocuted. Its been bugging me for months what this movie is, but I can't recall anymore! Can anyone help please? 

Final Destination 3 is set in a fairground, the characters all get on a rollercoaster that crashes killing most of them.
One character sneaks a video camera on the ride, could this be the 'making a film' part you remember?
One of the later deaths involve two girls who get burnt/electrocuted on tanning beds.
